# How to create a list out of results from a simple maths equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I know how to do this using a loop, but interested what's a one liner pythonic way to do it.

For example, how would I get first 10 values of `y` for `y = x^2` or `y = log(x)` for integers of `x` ?

eg for x^2  [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]

Comment: What do you mean by `first 10 values`? Is `x` a `list`?

Comment: Are you expecting a list comprehension like `result = [x**2 for x in range(1,11)]` that generates the output as `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]`

Answer (score 2):

List expression

```
ys = [x ** 2 for x in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need the "map" function? for example:

```
# Python program to demonstrate working 
# of map. 
  
# Return double of n 
def addition(n): 
    return n + n 
  
# We double all numbers using map() 
numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4) 
result = map(addition, numbers) 
print(list(result))
```

the output is:
[2, 4, 6, 8]

Above code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/